# mongodb empty host error in docker

Tags: mongodb, docker

[image]I am trying to connect and run mongodb in docker. But it is showing error.

> $docker pull mongo $ docker run -it mongo sh -c 'exec mongo
>   "$MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_ADD R:$MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_PORT/PMSDB" '
>   MongoDB shell version v3.6.2 connecting to: mongodb://:/PMSDB
>   2018-01-30T10:31:34.696+0000 E QUERY [thread1] **Error: Empty host
>   component parsing HostAndPort from ":" :**
>   connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13 @(connect):1:6 exception:
>   connect failed
>   user2@system2 MINGW64 ~/sample $

How to resolve this

Comment: first tou don't have to call pull mongo, run command will call it if the image does not exist in local repository. Then I did you define `$MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_ADD` and `$MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_PORT/PMSDB` en vars?

Comment: mongo image is already in docker container. when I try to run mongo image by using  docker run mongo .. It is displaying above displayed message

Comment: as you can see when you start mongo docker container without changing port it starts correctly but when you start docker container with new port as env var witch not defined you get error.

Comment: how do i resolve this.

Comment: could you share  the result of `echo  $MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_ADD`

Comment: what is echo here, where should I use and get the result. in docker quickstart terminal window?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164172/discussion-between-andolsi-zied-and-n15).